# Firebase web logout() not redirect to index page

Tags: firebase

I am using firebase auth for my web project. I use the code below to sign out but it keeps redirect me to homepage instead of index page.

```
function logout(){
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
      document.location.href = 'index.html';
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
}
```

I have tried this code but its not redirect to anywhere like the button is not function at all.

```
firebase.auth().signOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

`firebase.auth().signOut();` just quits the user session, so data won't be transfered any more. you have to redirect by your own for example like this with a function:

```
function logout(){
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    window.location.replace("login.html");
  }
```

In your html you can call the cuntion name `logout()` with `onclick` then.